# How to Display user profile picture next to welcome name?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile, custom-masterpage

I need Html code to display the user profile picture next to welcome name,I followed this tutorial [showing-current-logged-in-users-profile-picture-next-to-welcome-menu-in-sharepoint-2013](https://nishantrana.me/2013/10/24/showing-current-logged-in-users-profile-picture-next-to-welcome-menu-in-sharepoint-2013/) .It's Not working in HTML master page. I used as

```
<!–SPM:–>


<!–SPM: –>
```

Giving parse error as control not found. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tutorial , you should add the following code at `Master Page` file rather than HTML file. and try to use `"` rather than `”` as the following

```
<%@Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

add this

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader runat="server" />

<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyImage PropertyName="PictureUrl" style="float: left; height: 20px;" ShowPlaceholder="true" id="PictureUrlImage" runat="server"/>
```

**Note**: Don't forget to take a backup before modifying the Master Page

Comment: I can't save my master page file by Using SharePoint designer,Its better if I get a Html Code for that @Qassas

Comment: do you have checked-out master page file > then right click on it select edit file in advanced mode ? now you can edit and save your master page file , also don't forget to take a backup

Comment: I checked out the master page file,while saving the file i got this server error: This file may not be moved or renamed or deleted  or otherwise edited @Qassas

Comment: Dear @SuriyaadevanBalu check this for your new issue http://www.techmikael.com/2013/02/issue-with-creating-copy-of.html , please tell me the result

Comment: Qassas I need to Show to the user profile picture from  profile property without using my sites? Is it possible to change  the above properties @Qassas

Comment: @SuriyaadevanBalu yes, it's possible, just make sure the UPS has been configured, and Picture property is imported ,  but it requires additional coding ,

Comment: ya UPS is configured and picture Property are imported @Qassas